# How to sort by value linkhashmap nest list object

Tags: java, java-8

I have an object looking like:

```
public class Result {
    long id;
    Map<String,Object> map; 

    // constructor + getters + setters
}
```

I put some thing value into object result and my object result look like:

```
Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("created_at", "2020-10-10");

Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("created_at", "2020-10-12");

Result result1 = new Result(1, map1);
Result result2 = new Result(2, map2);

List<Result> results = Arrays.asList(result1, result2);
```

How to sort list results by value ascending date from the map?

Comment: What have you tried by yourself?

Comment: `results.sort(Comparator.comparing(r -> r.getValues().get("created_at").toString()))`

Comment: Could you try printing in console the Results array and then add here ? The Result do not seem to be correct. Can help better.

Comment: Next time, provide a minimal sample that can be compiled.

Comment: Consider to safe the dates as/convert the dates to `LocalDate`. Then, it might be easier to compare them than just as `String`. Have a look at this [article of Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-creating-localdate-with-values) to get some ideas on how to create `LocalDate` objects out of `String` objects.